# what is the cleanest way to run 4 commands 1 after the other using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run 4 commands, one after the other, using ansible.

```sh
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --wds-set-autoconnect-settings=disabled,roaming-allowed
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --wds-get-autoconnect-settings
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart redbox-lte.service
```

```yaml
- name: run first command
  shell: qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --wds-set-autoconnect-settings=disabled,roaming-allowed
  become: true
```

etc. for every command

I was wondering what best practice is; I am sure that must be a better way.

Comment: 1) You can run the last 2 commands at once in a single task that will respect idempotency out of the box using the [`systemd` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) 2) if you can't find a specific module for `qmicli` (I didn't...), check if you can use `command` instead of `shell` then pass the commands in a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html). Alternatively, if you really need `shell`, you can pass the commands at once in a single multi-line string.

Comment: `command1 && command2` , this will run both commands , however, `command2` will only run when `command1` is successful. you can extend this if you find it fine.

Comment: That's a valuable comment THX

Answer (score 1):

The following tasks accomplish what you want to do:

```yaml
- name: Execute
  become: true
  shell: |
    qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --wds-set-autoconnect-settings=disabled,roaming-allowed && \
    qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p --wds-get-autoconnect-settings

- name: Restart redbox-lte
  become: true
  systemd:
    state: restarted
    daemon_reload: yes
    name: redbox-lte
```

However, regarding best practice, you should always make sure to write your ansible scripts in an idempotent matter and print proper tasks statuses. For that reason (especially for the `shell` module) you should use options like [`changed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed).
Once you ensured that your `shell` module is only being executed when needed you should go ahead and define the `systemd` restart as a [handler](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html), which will only execute if there was a change in the task that triggers the handler.